# What breakdown voltage of TVS diode should I choose for circuits interfacing with vehicle 12V battery?

Tags: diodes, zener, esd, tvs

I want to add ESD protection on my circuits that interface with vehicle 12V.  My understanding is vehicle battery can reach up to 15V.  Looking at [image: datasheet below], I can either pick 14.2V or 25V for min Vbr.  I prefer this device because it supports multiple channels.  Give the product intended for automotive, I assume the diodes should be compatible with vehicle voltages. What min breakdown voltage should I choose if my circuits can handle only up to 20V? (Let's just ignore the power of TVS for now).  Thanks.

Datasheet: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/6c/ab/7a/c8/ed/5a/4e/94/DM00231412.pdf/files/DM00231412.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00231412.pdf

Comment: Are you looking to use this on your circuit's power supply input, on control signal inputs, or both?

Comment: @brhans, yes for both.  Thanks.

Comment: You might want to consider the ‘load dump’ condition.

Comment: Kartman has pointed out the issue I suspected you've not considered. A little TVS will not protect your circuit from a 'load dump' condition where your vehicle's nominal 12V rail can briefly rise well above its normal voltage. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_dump) says that you could expect as high as 40V for as long as 400ms. With a 14.2V or even 25V TVS trying to clamp that, the current from the alternator through your TVS will be limited only be the wiring and will likely turn your TVS into a smoking cinder (followed shortly by the rest of your circuit).

Answer (score 1):

These ESD diodes are meant for data lines, not supply lines.
For automotive applications, supply lines and data lines are not subject to the same standards.
ISO7637-2 for supply lines and ISO 7637-3 for data lines.
In addition, you must take care of reverse battery, jump start and load dump.

I recommend reading this AN where they explained all the automotive transients (ESD and longer surges for both data lines and power rails) and how protection devices work:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2689-protection-of-automotive-electronics-from-electrical-hazards-guidelines-for-design-and-component-selection-stmicroelectronics.pdf

To start somewhere, I can say that for most of the cases (but not all, it really depends on your application constraints, ICs vulnerability etc…) a 600 W TVS like [SM6TY](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sm6t36ay.pdf) or [SMA6TY](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sma6t36ay.pdf) can do the job for supply rails.
Most of the time, VBR between 33V and 42V are adapted when a central load is implemented in the car. Maybe 36V VBR is the most popular.
You have to place the protection as close as possible to the input supply connector.
2 options here:

1. You select a unidirectional TVS like SMA6T36AY so in that case you place a diode for reverse polarity blocking between the connector and the unidirectional TVS.
2. You select a bidirectional TVS like SMA6T36CAY so in that case you place this TVS just after the power input connector and then a diode for reverse polarity blocking.
   For less than 1A, you may look into [STTH102AY](https://www.st.com/en/diodes-and-rectifiers/stth102-y.html). Here again if you need more than 1A you will need to select another current rating. It is just an example to give a starting point.

Then for datalines it depends on the signal frequency and voltage range. If it is for CAN bus or LIN bus it is quite well-defined and specific protection devices exist.
If it is for other kind of signals, then we need more details.